# Pandas/SciPy - High Commit Memory Usage - Windows

Tags: python, pandas, windows

*Update: After posting this question I discovered the same issue was occurring with SciPy. I have updated the title so others may discover this post. I have left the original question unchanged. A solution is provided below.*

Original Question:

Is there a way to reduce the commit memory usage of Pandas on Windows when multiprocessing?

I have written a multiprocessing application using Python on Windows and am getting MemmoryErrors, driven largely by importing Pandas. in each sub-process. When importing Pandas I notice in taskmgr an increase in commit memory of roughly 0.5GB. When multiprocessing accross 16 cores, this becomes a significant issue as 8GB of commit memory is being used up before the "real" code runs. This problem leaves insufficient commit memory for the application, causing MemoryErrors to be thrown. The private working memory doesn't increase in the same way so RAM is not the constraint.

I will look to have the pagefile increased but this is not an ideal solution as the application will be rolled over to others. Is there a way on Windows to reduce the import size, for example by sharing the import across sub-processes or are there any particular versions/flags that can reduce the allocation being implemented by pandas?

**Python**: 3.11 (64bit), **Pandas**: 2.0.3, **OS**: Windows 10 Enterprise

Comment: I would advise to use `dask` instead of `pandas`: The syntax is similar and `dask` parallelism and memory nicely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is caused by OpenBLAS which assigns 30MB for each core. On my 16-core machine, this resulted in 480MB being allocated for each sub-process. The same issue occurs with SciPy. As I had both running I had about 1GB being committed for each sub-process.

The solution for me was to limit the number of threads available to OpenBLAS which can be done by setting the environment variable 'OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS'.

Here is test code which highlights the issue and provides the fix.

```
import os
os.environ["OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS"] = "1" # Comment out to see original issue

import pandas as pd
import scipy 
import time

b = scipy.optimize.Bounds # Bounds is a function, assigning it to b is to cause optimize to be initialised

time.sleep(60)
```

**Issue:**

[image: Issue:]

**Fix:**

[image: Fix]